# Divide string into associtive array

Tags: php, arrays, split, associative-array, preg-split

I have a string:

```
$string = 'A0695/16 NOTAMN Q) EHAA/QARLT/I /NBO/E /000/999/5155N00430E073 A) EHAA B) 1605260001 C) 1608260900 EST E) REF AIP NETHERLANDS ENR 3.2 UT601 ADD TO ROUTE REMARKS: NOT AVBL FOR TRAFFIC DEP/ARR ETNG, EDDK AND ETNN DURING THE OPENING OF EHEH 0600-2300 (0500-2200). THESE FLIGHTS WILL HAVE TO REROUTE.';
```

I would like to split this string into an associative array.

```
$result['Q)'] = 'EHAA/QARLT/I /NBO/E /000/999/5155N00430E073';
$result['A)'] = 'EHAA';
$result['B)'] = '1605260001';
$result['C)'] = '1608260900 EST';
```

etc.

I managed to get it into an array with:

```
$result = preg_split("/.\)/", $string);
```

It gives me an array but I need the keys to be `'a)', 'b)'` etc.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It might be better to take a step back an look at how you created that string, maybe that would be a better place to make a change

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_match_all` function with specific regexp pattern(*named submasks*) and `array_combine` function(to get a respective key/value pairs):

```
$string = 'A0695/16 NOTAMN Q) EHAA/QARLT/I /NBO/E /000/999/5155N00430E073 A) EHAA B) 1605260001 C) 1608260900 EST E) REF AIP NETHERLANDS ENR 3.2 UT601 ADD TO ROUTE REMARKS: NOT AVBL FOR TRAFFIC DEP/ARR ETNG, EDDK AND ETNN DURING THE OPENING OF EHEH 0600-2300 (0500-2200). THESE FLIGHTS WILL HAVE TO REROUTE.';

preg_match_all("/(?<k>[A-Z]\)) (?<v>.+?)(?= [A-Z]\)|$)/", $string, $matches);

// 'k'/'v' are key/value
$result = array_combine($matches['k'], $matches['v']);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Q)] => EHAA/QARLT/I /NBO/E /000/999/5155N00430E073
    [A)] => EHAA
    [B)] => 1605260001
    [C)] => 1608260900 EST
    [E)] => REF AIP NETHERLANDS ENR 3.2 UT601 ADD TO ROUTE REMARKS: NOT AVBL FOR TRAFFIC DEP/ARR ETNG, EDDK AND ETNN DURING THE OPENING OF EHEH 0600-2300 (0500-2200). THESE FLIGHTS WILL HAVE TO REROUTE.
)
```

Comment: Your way is clearly the best. Note that you can remove the option `PREG_SET_ORDER` and build the result without using `foreach`, like this: `$result = array_combine($matches['k'], $matches['v']);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks for the useful hint. I've simplified the answer

Answer (score 1):

Another goofy solution for the goofy format, because why not.

```
  $string = 'A0695/16 NOTAMN Q) EHAA/QARLT/I /NBO/E /000/999/5155N00430E073 A) EHAA B) 1605260001 C) 1608260900 EST E) REF AIP NETHERLANDS ENR 3.2 UT601 ADD TO ROUTE REMARKS: NOT AVBL FOR TRAFFIC DEP/ARR ETNG, EDDK AND ETNN DURING THE OPENING OF EHEH 0600-2300 (0500-2200). THESE FLIGHTS WILL HAVE TO REROUTE.';

  $foo = preg_split('/([A-Z]\)) /', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  $ret = [];
  foreach (range(1, count($foo) - 1, 2) as $i)
  {
    $ret[$foo[$i]] = $foo[$i + 1];
  }
  print_r($ret);
```

Prints:

```
Array (
    [Q)] => EHAA/QARLT/I /NBO/E /000/999/5155N00430E073 
    [A)] => EHAA 
    [B)] => 1605260001 
    [C)] => 1608260900 EST 
    [E)] => REF AIP NETHERLANDS ENR 3.2 UT601 ADD TO ROUTE REMARKS: NOT AVBL FOR TRAFFIC DEP/ARR ETNG, EDDK AND ETNN DURING THE OPENING OF EHEH 0600-2300 (0500-2200). THESE FLIGHTS WILL HAVE TO REROUTE. )
```

Answer (score 0):

More fanciful than efficient but it does the job:

```
$p = preg_split('~(?<!\S)([A-Z]\))\s+~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$result = [];
if (count($p) > 1) {
    unset($p[0]);
    while($p) { 
        $result[array_shift($p)] = array_shift($p);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```